# Fixed divs and inside of iframe elements

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a problem with html code. I have tried many solutions but i haven't solved my problem. 
Excatly my problem is ; 
if i used two div inside of html page and both divs must be contains iframe element, i have never seen correct html page in browser.

Note : each div must have position:fixed css attribute.

Example code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
     body{margin:0px;}

     .modalWrapper
     {
        position:fixed;
        display:block;
        width:500px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
        margin:0px; 
        top:50px;
        left:500px;
        z-index:100;
     }

     .modalHeader{ width:100%; height:80px; }
     .modalNavigator { background-color:#ccc; height:220px; }

     .bottomWrapper
     {
        position:fixed;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:300px;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
        margin:0px; 
        bottom:0px;
        z-index:99;
     }

     .bottomHeader{ width:100%; height:80px; }
     .bottomNavigator{ background-color:#ccc; height:220px; }

    </style>

</head>
<body>


<div>       
    <div class="modalWrapper">
       <div class="modalHeader">
        Modal       
       </div>
       <div class="modalNavigator">

         <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.yahoo.com" id="Iframe1"
                style="height: 220px; width: 100%;" scrolling="no"/>    
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottomWrapper">
       <div class="bottomHeader">
        Bottom       
       </div>
       <div class="bottomNavigator">
         <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com.tr" id="Iframe2"
                style="height: 220px; width: 100%;" scrolling="no"/>
       </div>
    </div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What is the error with the code you have?

Comment: What browser are you using? I checked this out in IE8 and it looked fine (both iframes showed their contents properly).

Comment: Do you want arrange center screen for both div elements?

Comment: I have two divs inside of page. 
It should display two divs on the page (with black headers).

When i tried to add <input type="button" value="Test it" />  instead of  <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.yahoo.com" ... 
It's working.

Comment: On the other hand, it shown two divs with iframes but, divs doest'n show correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<iframe [...]/>
```

Try:

```
<iframe [...]></iframe>
```

I would check out this question for more information on why this helps: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)